# Отправка писем при регистрации с активацией

Tags: php

Ребята, почему-то не отправляет письмо пользователям. Само сообщение о том, что сообщение на почту отправлено выходит. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, код:

```
//    Проверяем, есть ли ошибки
if    ($result2=='TRUE')
{
      $result3    = mysql_query ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
      $myrow3    = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
      $activation    = md5($myrow3['id']).md5($login);
```

$subject    = "Подтверждение регистрации";
            $message    = "Здравствуйте! Спасибо за регистрацию на v-sporte.net\nВаш логин:    ".$login."\n
            Перейдите    по ссылке, чтобы активировать ваш    аккаунт:\nhttp://v-sporte.net/activation.php?login=".$login."&code=".$activation."\nС    уважением,\n
            Администрация    v-sporte.net";//содержание сообщение
            mail($email,    $subject, $message, "Content-type:text/plane;    Charset=windows-1251\r\n");

```
        echo    "Вам на E-mail выслано письмо с cсылкой, для подтверждения регистрации.    Внимание! Ссылка действительна 1 час. <a href='index.php'>Главная    страница</a>"; //говорим о    отправленном письме пользователю
}
```

*Обновление*

```
if(mail($email,    $subject, $message, "Content-type:text/plane;    Charset=windows-1251\r\n"))//отправляем сообщение
{        
   echo    "Вам на E-mail выслано письмо с cсылкой, для подтверждения регистрации.    Внимание! Ссылка действительна 1 час. <a href='index.php'>Главная    страница</a>"; //говорим о    отправленном письме пользователю
}        
else 
    echo "Ошибка! Вы не зарегистрированы.";
```

Вот так получилось, но теперь даже не выходит само сообщение об отправке и нет письма на почте.

Comment: Content-type:text/plane  ?

Comment: Внимание! Ссылка действительна 1 час.

Ты не поверишь. Некоторая почта идёт больше часа.

Answer (score 4):

Оберните функцию mail() в if(), что бы это выглядело примерно так:

```
if( mail($email, $subject, $message, "Content-type:text/plane; Charset=windows-1251\r\n")){
     echo "Вам на E-mail выслано письмо с cсылкой, для подтверждения регистрации.";
    }else echo "Произошла ошибка почтовой функции";
```

Если ошибки не будет - копайте в сторону вашей почтовой программы. Возможно стоит спросить у техподдержки вашего хостинга, почему у вас письма не уходят. Но это только в том случае, если mail() вернет false. Как-то так.

Comment: Сообщение какое именно не выдается? Напишите его.

Comment: До этого выходило сообщение, о том что оно отправлено на почту и действительна час.

Comment: это означает, что у вас либо проблемы с программой, которая отвечает за отправку писем, либо с переменными в функции mail(). Что бы это проверить попробуйте отправлять письма на определенный адрес со статическими аргументами. Пример: mail("joecool@example.com", "My Subject", "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3");

Comment: Сейчас просто выводит ошибку "Произошла ошибка почтовой функции"...

Comment: Как я уже писал, Вам надо обратиться в таком случае к хостинг провайдеру. Возможно для Вашего сайта заблокирован 21-ый порт (который отвечает за отправку почты). Попробуйте выполнить данную функцию, что бы быть уверенным на 100%

mail("joecool@example.com", "My Subject", "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3");
joecool@example.com замените на Ваш email